# Radom Forest Prediction Intervals using a categorical response variable

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, prediction, r-caret

I'm trying to get prediction intervals from a random forest model that has a categorical response variable. Ideally, I would like to see how confident the model is for classifying an observation into a given response category.

On the last line of my code you'll see a `predict()` that works when the `interval =` argument is not included. When I include the "interval =" I get an error. Any idea on how to get prediction intervals for the output?

```
# Load libraries
library(data.table)
library(randomForest)
library(caret)

# Set seed
set.seed(123)

# Load the necessary data
df.0 <- diamonds
setDT(df.0)

# set up the cross-validation parameters
control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
               number = 10)
metric <- "Accuracy"
mtry <- seq(from = 1,
            to = length(unique(df.0$cut)),
            by = 1)
tunegrid <- expand.grid(mtry = mtry)

# Add rownames so we can use as index
df.0[, indexNum := .I]
trainer <- df.0[ ,.SD[sample(x = .N, size = (.N * 0.9))], by = cut] # Pull 90% of each cut into training
tester <- df.0[!trainer, on = c("indexNum")]

# Remove index number
tester <- tester[, ":=" (indexNum = NULL)] 
trainer <- trainer[, ":=" (indexNum = NULL)] 

# build a model and assess its accuracy via 10-fold cross validation
rf_mod <- 
  train(
    x = trainer[, .(x, y, z, depth, table)],
    y = trainer$cut,
    method = "rf",
    metric = "Accuracy",
    tuneGrid = tunegrid
  )

# check out which mtry value was best
plot(rf_mod)

# test the model against the test data
cut_pred <- predict(rf_mod, newdata = tester[, .(x, y, z, depth, table), interval = "prediction")
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. It sounds like you want to find the best way to ignore inconvenient data. (That defeats the purpose of analysis. Actually, when you remove randomness you've already created results that aren't meaningful.) Have you considered looking at the predictor variables' influences? If you do, add `importance = T` to your `train` call. It's a great way to see what is and isn't helping you get that accurate class label. If not, you might want to take a look at the package `lime`. You more on `lime` [here](https://github.com/thomasp85/lime).

Comment: To clarify, I'd just like to get the prediction intervals for each predicted value. 

In other words, for a given row of data the model will predict which category it should be assigned to. How do I get a the probability of the category it was assigned to? I think this is how many just knowing how many trees are assigned to each category for each observation.

Comment: `predict(..., type = "prob")` looks to me is what you need.

Comment: predict(..., type = "prob") did it! Thank you so much!